# Inserting a Bitmap on another Bitmap on certain position

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I need to position a bitmap onto another bitmap.
I use this method for this:

```
   private Bitmap addImageToBitmap(Bitmap inputBitmap, Bitmap signatureBitmap) {
        Bitmap Rbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Rbitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(signatureBitmap, -9, Rbitmap.getHeight() - signatureBitmap.getHeight() - 10, null);
        canvas.save();
        return Rbitmap;
    }
```

However, I have no idea how to specify where exactly it will be placed?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you wnat to overlay a bitmap onto the other..??

Comment: Yes, the result would be the original bitmap with the other (much smaller) bitmap placed on it, on a certain position

Answer (score 0):

just take a imageview in a framelayout and then place an other imageview of anysize..on it...it will complete your task..

did you got my point..??

Mark it up..if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
void    drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, float x, float y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)
```

Use x and y to draw the bitmap where you want it to be.

And regarding the stride:

> The number of colors in the array between rows (must be >= width or <= -width).

Paint is optional and can be null.